# How does tensorflow tf.contrib.image.rotate works?

Tags: tensorflow

I'm new in using tensorflow and also python and play little bit with it and can't figure out how `tf.contrib.image.rotate` works that i can use it as `tensor` for example in `tf.cast` operation.

Maybe someone can help me out to figure out how it can be used?

Greetz

Answer (score 5):

You are mixing two separate tensorflow functions.

**`tf.contrib.image.rotate`**: This function is used for rotating images at any degree of your choice.

```
X_img =  # Your image or batch of images
degree_angle = 45 # In degrees
radian = degree_angle * math.pi / 180
tf_img = tf.contrib.image.rotate(X_img, radian)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    rotated_img = sess.run(tf_img)
```

**`tf.cast`**: Used to cast the dtype of tensor from one form to another. Example of converting to float32 format.

```
casted_tensor = tf.cast(input_tensor, tf.float32)
```

Comment: Can you also tell me how to parse `X_img`?

Tried:

    file_reader = tf.read_file(file_name, input_name)
    X_img = tf.image.decode_jpeg(file_reader, channels = 3, name='jpeg_reader')

But python crashed..

Comment: @QSpot I will suggest you to make use of `matplotlib.image.imread` function to read images.

Comment: Didn't worked for me can you show whole process from load image (jpg as well) from file system, rotate and cast into floaing type?

Answer (score 1):

For those who are still looking here, starting in TensorFlow 2.x `tf.contrib` is deprecated, and so `tf.contrib.image.rotate` will no longer work.

Instead you can use **`tfa.image.rotate`** from the `tensorflow_addons` library. This function rotates an image counterclockwise and takes an angle in radians as an input.

```
img = ... #insert image(s) here
angle = 60 #in degrees
angle_radians = angle * math.pi / 180
rotated_img = tfa.image.rotate(img, angle_radians)
```

Comment: ok, so they both take an angle in radians as an input